# Using redis to emails queue in many servers environment

Tags: redis

In my production environment there are 7 parallel servers. I use redis to make emails queue like that:

```
$this->getRedis()->lpush('mailsQueue', serialize($mail));
```

And the daemon that is listening to the queue:

```
do {
    $mail = $this->getRedis()->rpop('mailsQueue');

    if ($mail) {
        // sending an email
    }

    usleep(1000);
} while (true);
```

It works pretty well when the daemon is run in only one instance. But in production environment each of 7 servers has own daemon service. This makes a problem that sometimes, an email is sending couple times. It's because sometimes not only the one daemon service load the same email from "mailsQueue" list.

**How can I make sure, that the element load with "rpop" will be loaded the only one time regardless how many daemon services I've got run?**

Huge thanks for every help!

Comment: At the end of the day, Redis wasn't designed for that purpose... Look at RabbitMQ or something like this...

Answer (score 0):

Wierd, I would have that that rpop would be atomic.  You should be able to use MULTI to force a transaction so that no one else can interfear with that variable.

http://redis.io/topics/transactions

> All the commands in a transaction are serialized and executed sequentially. It can never happen that a request issued by another client is served in the middle of the execution of a Redis transaction. This guarantees that the commands are executed as a single isolated operation.

More info:

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Transactions.md